# Multiple tasks returns incorrect result

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, task

**What I need to do**

I need to start different instances of a class in a synchronous context using an async method.

**Application structure**

In my `console` application I've declared a `List<Bot>` class:

```
private List<Bot> _bots = new List<Bot>(new Bot[10]);
```

the class `Bot` contains some methods that takes data from internet, so these methods need to be waited. The method structure looks like this:

```
public class Bot
{
    Competition Comp { get; set; }

    public async Task StartAsync(int instance) 
    {
         string url = "";

         //based on the instance I take the data from different source.
         switch(instance)
         {
             case 0:
                url = "www.google.com";
                break;
             case 1:
                url = "www.bing.com";
                break;
         }

         //Comp property contains different groups.
         Comp.Groups = await GetCompetitionAsync(Comp, url);

         if(Comp.Groups.Count > 0)
         {
             foreach(var gp in group)
             {
                //add data inside database.
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

the `Competition` class have the following design:

```
public class Competition 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Groups { get; set; } 
}
```

I start all the instances of `Bot` class using the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _bots.Count - 1; i++)
{
   _bots[i].StartAsync(i);
}
```

this code will call different times `StartAsync` of `Bot` class, in this way, I can manage each instance of the bot, and I can eventually stop or start a specific instance in a separate method.

**The problem**

The method `GetCompetitionAsync` create a `List<string>`:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetCompetitionAsync(Competition comp, string url)
{
     if(comp == null)
        comp = new Competition();

     List<string> groups = new List<string();

     using (var httpResonse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
     {
        string content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //fill list groups
     }

     return groups;
}
```

essentially this method will fill the `List<string>` available in `Comp`. Now, if I execute a single instance of `StartAsync` all works well, but when I run multiple instances (as the for above), the `Comp` object (which contains the `Competition`) have all the properties `NULL`.

So seems that when I have multiple `Task` running the `synchronous` context doesn't wait the `async` context, which in this case fill the `List<string>`.
When the code reach this line: `if(Competition.Groups.Count > 0)` I get a `NULL` exception, because `Groups` is null, and other `Comp` properties are `NULL`.

How can I manage this situation?

**UPDATE**

After other attempts, I though to create a `List<Task>` instead of a `List<Bot>`:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(new Task[10]);
```

then instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _bots.Count - 1; i++)
{
   _bots[i].StartAsync(i);
}
```

I did:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting " + i);

    if (tasks[i] == null)
        tasks[i] = new Task(async () => await new Bot().StartAsync(i));
```

apparently all is working well, I got no errors. The problem is: why? I though to something like a `deadlock`, that I can't even solve using `ConfigureAwait(false);`.

The last solution also doesn't allow me to access to `Bot` method because is now a `Task`.

**UPDATE 2**

Okay maybe I gotcha the issue. Essentially the `await` inside the asynchronous method `StartAsync` is trying to comeback on the main thread, meanwhile the main thread is busy waiting the task to complete, and this will create a `deadlock`.

That's why moving the `StartAsync()` inside a `List<Task>` has worked, 'cause now the `async` call is now running on a thread pool thread, it doesn't try to comeback to the main thread, and everything seems to works. But I can't use this solution for the reasons explained above.

Comment: Add a constructor to class Competition which accepts no parameters and inside that constructor initialize your `List<string>` property to a `new List<string>`, that should get rid of the null exception.

Comment: @ryanwilson Yes but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @RyanWilson this will no fix the problem anyway, if I start a single instance the `Groups` are filled correctly, if I have multiple instance running I get the error, so your solution is a fix, but no really a fix

Comment: all my efforts to write a good question are wasted, I do not really know why I got the downvote, at least explain

Comment: I am not sure why you are creating an array and passing it to the `List`. That is very odd so I wouldn't do that. Also, the method `GetCompetitionAsync` does not require the `Competition` parameter, don't even send it; make sure to create it in the calling code. Both these changes may not fix your issue but your code will be cleaner.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I did some changed in the question for explain better what the code does, but the real code contains what you said, thanks but these changes are not the real problem. PS: if you mean: `Bot[10]` I have created a specific number of element to instantiate

Comment: I know that's not the problem and I mentioned that in my comment. `new Bot[10]` will not create bots so I am not sure what's the point of that.

Comment: I think there is an error in your example. `async Task GetCompetitionAsync` won't compile. Shouldn't it return a `Task<List<string>>`?

Comment: @JohnWu I fixed the example, thanks for pointing out, it's not the real problem though

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you may have an issue in `GetCompetitionAsync`. Perhaps return a hard coded list `await Task.Delay(500); return new List<string>{ "Test Passed!" };`. Try that and see if you still have an issue. If you don't, the issue is in this method. And btw the return type is still wrong, it should be `Task<List<string>>`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I tried what you suggest, and I still get the same problem

Comment: I find that really hard to believe. There is something you are doing that you are not showing us. How about you eliminate all the async stuff and see you if you still have the issue. If you do, then at least you know it has nothing to do with asynchronousity

Comment: @CodingYoshi It's quite difficult for me replicate the exact code, there a lot of classes involved. I discovered this problem when I implemented the asynchronous logic, in the synchronous modality all works well.

Comment: @CodingYoshi could you please check my update? I discovered some new interesting things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm prefer use Threads instead of Tasks. IMHO, Threads more simple for understanding.
Note: seems that property Bot.Comp in your code is NOT initialized! I  fix this issue.
My version of your code:

```
public class Bot
{
    Competition Comp { get; set; }
    System.Thread _thread;
    private int _instance;

    public Bot()
    {
        Comp = new Competition ();
    }
    public void Start(int instance) 
    {
        _instance = instance;
        _thread = new Thread(StartAsync);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private void StartAsync() 
    {
         string url = "";

         //based on the instance I take the data from different source.
         switch(_instance)
         {
             case 0:
                url = "www.google.com";
                break;
             case 1:
                url = "www.bing.com";
                break;
         }

         //Comp property contains different groups.
         GetCompetitionAsync(Comp, url);

         if(Comp.Groups.Count > 0)
         {
             foreach(var gp in group)
             {
                //add data inside database.
             }
         }
     }

     public List<string> GetCompetitionAsync(Competition comp, string url)
     {
          if(comp.groups == null)  comp.groups = new List<string>();

          using (var httpResonse = httpClient.GetAsync(url))
          {
             string content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             //fill list groups
          }
          return groups;
     }
}
```

Then we run threads:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _bots.Count - 1; i++)
{
   _bots[i].Start(i);
}
```

Each instance of Bot starts method private void StartAsync() in it's own thread.

Note a implementation of method Bot.Start():

```
public void Start(int instance) 
{
    _instance = instance;
    _thread = new Thread(StartAsync); //At this line: set method Bot.StartAsync as entry point for new thread.
    _thread.Start();//At this line: call of _thread.Start() starts new thread and returns **immediately**.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't understand a thing: your code run a single instance of `Bot`? I should create different threads for "n" instance of the bot, eg: 9 - 10.

Comment: I tried your code, and seems to work as my last solution. I have to do other tests to be sure, but in the meantime +1

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is far simpler if you think in terms of lists and "pure" functions-- functions that accept input and return output. Don't pass in something for them to fill or mutate.

For example, this function accepts a string and returns the groups:

```
List<string> ExtractGroups(string content)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    //Populate list
    return  list;
}
```

This function accepts a URL and returns its groups.

```
async Task<List<string>> GetCompetitionAsync(string url)
{
    using (var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
    {
        string content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return ExtractGroups(content);
    }
 }
```

And this function accepts a list of URLs and returns all of the groups as one list.

```
async Task<List<string>> GetAllGroups(string[] urls)
{
    var tasks = urls.Select( u => GetCompetitionAsync(u) );
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return tasks.SelectMany( t => t.Result );
}
```

You can then stuff the data into the database as you had planned.

```
var groups = GetAllGroups( new string[] { "www.google.com", "www.bing.com" }  );        
foreach(var gp in groups)
{
    //add data inside database.
}
```

See how much simpler it is when you break it down this way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so you suggest to edit the method that fill the group? If so: why when I execute a single instance all works well, and with multiple instance I have the null problem? I'm not really sure that this is a "method structure" problem, but I could be wrong

Comment: Yes I do. This is something we've learned from the functional programming paradigm: when you use variables that can be mutated, you can end up with concurrency issues, and when you eliminate them, they go away completely. The alternative is to use locks and a ConcurrentBag or something of that kind, and it won't perform as well, and the code isn't nearly as pretty. I strongly recommend you change your approach and adopt this kind of thinking, if it is feasible.

Comment: could you please check my update? I guess I discovered what the problem really is